# How to add new tab function in PyQt5 and python web browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebenginepage

I'm making a web browser in PyQt5 and Python I want to add [open new tab] feature. I'm using QWebEnginePage.createWindow but I don't know how to do this.

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def createWindow(self, MainWindow):
    if MainWindow == QWebEnginePage.WebBrowserTab:
        self.webView = MainWindow()
        self.webView.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)
        self.webView.show()
        return self.webView
    return super(MainWindow, self).createWindow(MainWindow)

    self.browser = QWebEngineView()
    self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"))

    #QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows.createWindow()

    self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)
    self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
```

Comment: You could explain what you want to do

Comment: There's qtabwidget

Comment: I want to make a web browser like chrome which can open new tabs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make tabbed browser with qwebengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948871/how-to-make-tabbed-browser-with-qwebengine)