# How could i add a bookmark and tabs function in PySide6?

Tags: python, browser, pyside6, qwebengineview

I'm trying to make a web browser but i cant find a good tutorial for bookmarks and tabs in my web browser called **RadonNet** I'm using `PySide6` because i want my software to be open source

I also use `QWebEngineView` which makes it harder to find tutorials for my browser

Sure. Theres Bookmarks and Tabs Tutorials but they will not work with `QWebEngineView`

Anything to solve this?

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QToolBar
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction  # Corrected import for QAction
from PySide6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

class Browser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('RadonNet')

`your text`        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))

        # Navigation toolbar
        self.nav_bar = QToolBar("Navigation")
        self.addToolBar(self.nav_bar)

        # Back button
        back_btn = QAction('Back', self)
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        self.nav_bar.addAction(back_btn)

        # Forward button
        forward_btn = QAction('Forward', self)
        forward_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        self.nav_bar.addAction(forward_btn)

        # Refresh button
        refresh_btn = QAction('Refresh', self)
        refresh_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        self.nav_bar.addAction(refresh_btn)

        # Home button
        home_btn = QAction('Home', self)
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        self.nav_bar.addAction(home_btn)

        # URL bar
        self.url_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.url_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        self.nav_bar.addWidget(self.url_bar)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('http://www.google.com'))

    def navigate_to_url(self):
        url = self.url_bar.text()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.setApplicationName('RadonNet')
    window = Browser()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried tutorials but none of them are compatible with `QWebEngineView`.
There are very few posts about bookmarks and tabs for `PySides`/`QT` `WebEngineView`
And none of them work.
So I'm forced to ask stack overflow

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948871/how-to-make-tabbed-browser-with-qwebengine). I think you could use also PyQt tutorials

Comment: "none of them work". Tutorials are not meant to always work out of the box, you should understand their principles and eventually do further research on your own. If you *did* do all that, then please provide a valid [mre] of your attempts. We do not provide how-tos or generic guides to such aspects, as that's not the purpose of StackOverflow. Besides, you're only allowed one question or specific subject per post (and you're asking about two very distinct aspects). For tabbing, look into the QTabWidget and QTabBar classes; for bookmarks, it's completely up to you.